# How can the Mach-Zehnder interferometer results be consistent with an epistemic view on the wavefunction (WF)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, interferometry, epistemology

If the epistemic view on WF is that something is happening in the mind of the observer (e.g. he observed something and then the WF changed for him) then how is this view consistent with the results from Mach Zehnder interferometer (MZI) for just one particle, which are well known.

Namely: If one changes the phase in one leg (by increasing its length or by placing phase plates etc.) then this action changes the result on the output of MZI completely (one can extinguish the intensity (have no clicks at all) in one of the two detectors placed at the output of the second Beamsplitter (BS) of MZI and redirect it toward the other detector (have all clicks here)).

So the WF is changed as a consequence of the physical action (phase lag induction) and not on paper (in the head of the observer). One can even imagine that the observer on the second BS has no knowledge about the phase lag, which can be inducted by other experimentator or by a device. Of course the observer will see change in his results which are surely due to this event and not by some process in his mind.

So the epistemic view of the WF seems very improbable? Why do official physics stick to it? What do you think?

Comment: What are you defining as "official physics"? Is there some regulatory body that uses the epistemic view of the wavefunction?

Comment: Well I think Copenhagen defends epistemic view, though not directly but by denying the objectiveness of the WF (the underlying processes described by it). Nevertheless I realize now that it is a separate question (e.g. Copenhagen=epistemic). My main point is however whether MZI phenomena does rule out epistemic interpretations which are not explicitly regarded as inappropriate but even at the contrary (are vital element of many interpretations).

Comment: Isn't that the same applies to whatever the system?  I think you take the "happen in the head " too seriously or even in a wrong way. The observer should be the phase plate,  or the two branches of the diode, I think. However I admit that I'm trying my best to get the basic and I am not the most indicated person to interprete QM. I just commented as I do not see anything special in a MZD  that is not presented by a double slit etc.

Comment: @Alchimista, if the phase plate is responsible for the change of WF that means that the WF is objective (ontic) which is not the case in epistemic (and Copenhagen) views. I am not looking seriously on "happen in the head" but the epistemiologists do! The MZI is not special in any case but here the problem is most obvious for me (at least).

Comment: I would say that the final observer does not know if the WF changed.  I am not polemic.  Just duscussing. Again I will be more than happy if I could manage QM fully under a zero order interpretation :)